# Can't Add Null Character in C

Tags: c, null, character

I'm beginner in this website.

I want to add a null character to my file.

```
if (strcmp(is->fields[i], "\b") == 0)
{
    int len = atoi(is->fields[i + 1]);
    char bosluk = '\0';
    FILE *fp = fopen("cikis.dat", "a");
    for (int j = 0; j<len; j++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%c", bosluk);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

But it doesn't add null character in my file. Got an idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Idos: Why would one write a pointer to a file? And a _null pointer_ is a very different thing than **the** _null character_, resp. the value `0`.

Comment: check `strcmp(is->fields[i], "\b") == 0`, `len > 0`, `fp != NULL`

Comment: It hasn't to be null character. It could be space. I will try your code with && right? I mean if statement1 && statement2 && ...

Answer (score 0):

The null character is `'\0'`, not space `' '`, it is also used to terminate strings in C.

```
char bosluk = '\0';
fprintf(fp, "%c", bosluk);
```

`strcmp` compares two strings, `'\b'` is a integer constant, it's not a string, string literals are defined with double quotes in C.

Update:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("cikis.dat", "a");
if (strcmp(is->fields[i], "write") == 0)
{
      fprintf(fp, "Hello Hello");
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: @YunusHaznedar can you post some details on what does it not work?

Comment: Oh, do you think this if statement is wrong? if(strcmp(is->fields[i],'\b')==0)  Especially here -> '\b'  ? Cause my code is belong to this if-else block.

Comment: @YunusHaznedar There is no `if` statement in the code?

Comment: @YunusHaznedar that depends on your design of the program, the null character will be written if the `strcmp` returns 0.

Comment: This code contains 2 if statement. First if statement:                               if(strcmp(is->fields[i],"write")==0) and this block write "Hello" in file.          And this block is working. Second if statement:                            if(strcmp(is->fields[i],'\b')==0) and this block should write " " in file. For an example is->fields ([0]="write" [1]="\b" and [2]= write)                    Output must be: Hello -space- Hello

Comment: @YunusHaznedar do you want space or null character?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. I just wanna see: Hello    Hello

Comment: @YunusHaznedar in that case why not just white the string? See my code

Comment: So cunning :) Yeah, I just thought that before but my professor's worksheet doesn't contain that block. It has to be write space or null character when is->fields[i]="\b"

Comment: @YunusHaznedar please post the definition of is and the worksheet requirement

Comment: That worksheet is written in Turkish. And I wrote you that requirement. It's so simple actually. When statement see the "\b" write null or space in text file. It has to be easy peasy but I miss something. So tiny something.

Comment: Yeah, I think it does. But it doesn't. I'm gonna throw up bc of C Programming :(

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I don't know. All part of code is working. Except that if block. I think "\" symbol could be a problem.

Comment: That the point, it depends on what the program needs to do, \ starts an escape sequence

Comment: I'm gonna try just "b". And I will let you know the result. Thanks a lot my friend. I bother you. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello again, I tried a different way to solve problem. I used \\b instead of \b. And it worked!!!! A f**king symbol almost get cancer me. Thanks your comments my friend :)

Comment: @YunusHaznedar Then it is literally a string of '\\' and 'b', not the escaped '\b'. good to know you get it right anyway. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use

```
fprintf(fp, " ");
```

instead.

Comment: I tried once. It didn't work either :( And I'm so mad bc of that. It's such a small problem :/